# Windows 10 won't read specific SD card

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

My dad has a ThinkPad X230 running Windows 10. He'd been using an SD card to store some movies, but he can't read it on this new computer. It worked fine on his old Yoga, and it's perfectly readable under both Windows and Ubuntu on my computer. He's able to read other SD cards (same make and model) formatted the same way without a problem.

The device doesn't even register in Device Manager or Disk Management. I tried recreating an MBR partition table and reformatting it as exFAT, but it still doesn't see it.

Could it be "blacklisted" somehow by serial number or something? I recall that Windows keeps track of removable storage devices in order to use the right driver when they're plugged back in (or something like that). It seems odd that it would be driver-related though, since the other SD cards of the same make and model show up fine.

The hard drive/Windows installation was transferred from the Yoga (so this very Windows installation used to read it fine) but everything seems to run fine otherwise.

Comment: Are you using the built-in card reader? Do you have an external card reader you can try?

Comment: It's built-in and no, we don't have an external one.

Comment: Get an external card reader.